# Cobian backup archieve bit

Tags: backup

I want to backup my data with 2 different tasks in cobian backup. Task 1 will be using mirror backup of drive E in order to backup the data of it as is to my Local Drive H. Task 2 will be backing up the same data in differential mode to an external HDD. The problem I see is that whenever one of the tasks is executed, it will change the archieve bit and this would affect the other task. Is there a way to apply so the backups would'nt rely on the archieve bit ?

Comment: I forgot to add more information: Task 1 mirror uses incremental backup. There is also task 3 which backups some of the same data to disk on key in differential mode.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new task or edit an existing task, you will see the following in the "General" section.  One of the options is "Use file attribute logic".  If that option is checked, then it will use the archive attribute to determine if a file needs to be backed up for incremental/differential backups.  If you don't want the archive attribute to be used when backing up, then uncheck that box.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but When I unchecked it, the differential option became grayed and unavailable.